# Can someone induce cancer in another person

Tags: water, toxicity

Is it possible to poison someone's food on a daily basis in order to give them cancer?

The thing here is that i'm worried someone at my workplace might be poisoning other people's water (each employee has his own packs of water bottles at their desks, also, this person seems to have some mental issues). 
It is possible to put chemicals in a bottle with no water leaking via a syringe. So my fear is that this bad person (this person IS bad., believe me) may have poisoned, in a daily basis for 3 or 4 weeks, our water.

So the question is, could this person poison the bottles to make others get cancer? Or another highly dangerous disease?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour]. What you are posting here is worrisome and you should consider other actions than asking this question here. But in short, the scenario you are describing does not seem impossible to me - depends however on the knowledge and skills of the person you are asking about.

Answer (score 4):

> […] So the question is, could this person poison the bottles to make others get cancer? Or another highly dangerous disease?

Yes, in principle.

Information on known cancerogenic compounds can be found in **CMR** (**C**anceogenic, **M**utagenic and toxic to **R**eproduction) lists published by national organizations responsible for workplace safety.

In Germany, this would be the **IFA** (*Institut für Arbeitsschutz der Deutschen Gesetzlichen Unfallversicherung*).

[List with old nomenclature](http://publikationen.dguv.de/dguv/pdf/10002/kmr_alte_bezeichnungen_2014.pdf)

[List with new nomenclature](http://publikationen.dguv.de/dguv/pdf/10002/kmr_neue_bezeichnung_2014.pdf)

**I have added these lists just for the sake of completeness!**

If you suspect any of the activities that you described, contact the local authorities.